# Java SPI - Choosing a single implementation

Tags: java, serviceloader

Java SPI is simple to use when we want to find all available implementations of an interface or abstract class and perform an action with each:

```
ServiceLoader.load(SomeService.class)
    .forEach(service -> service.doSomething());
```

What is the idiom for choosing a single implementation from multiple available implementations? There are many services I can think of that don't make sense to operate with multiple instances.

We can use `iterator().next()` to just find the first implementation that comes back from ServiceLoader, but this doesn't offer the user a way to select which specific implementation they want to be picked up, if necessary. As far as I can tell, the iteration order is somewhat random and based upon the classpath ordering of the META-INF/services files which is not consistent.

Surely I am missing something and this is already taken care of without having to write our own 'if system property is set, load this class, else iterator.next from ServiceLoader'

Comment: The idiom is that the `Service` either chooses itself or returns null.