# Java SPI - Choosing a single implementation (using Java 17 modular system)

Tags: java

My question is based on this question

[Java SPI - Choosing a single implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140651/java-spi-choosing-a-single-implementation)

When we have multiple implementations is there any way (how to do it) to select **one specific**. From my standpoint it just doesn't make sense to do blindingly like this

```
ServiceLoader.load(SomeService.class)
    .forEach(service -> service.test());
```

I.e.

if I have three implementations of SomeService

```
interface SomeService {
    public void test();
}

public class SomeInterfaceImpl1 implements SomeService {
 <...>
}

public class SomeInterfaceImpl2 implements SomeService {
 <...>
}

public class SomeInterfaceImpl3 implements SomeService {
 <...>
}
```

How to select an implementation of SomeInterfaceImpl2?

Would doing something like this make any sense?

```
ServiceLoader.load(SomeService.class)
             .stream()
             .map(Provider::get)
             .filter( s -> s instanceof SomeInterfaceImp2)
             .limit(1)
             .forEach(s -> s.test())
         .
```

Comment: Did you try the code using streams? Did you get any results?